# How to Calculate temperature, given speed of sound and relative humidity?

Tags: acoustics, air, speed

I know the solution in reverse direction, but I find it very complex to go the other way around and calculate the temperature when given the speed of sound and relative humidity, any ideas?

Comment: Write down the equation you would use for the reverse problem, and then solve it for $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any particular reason you couldn't do this.  It just might be really hard in practice with real equipment, working out the sensitivities.  I would first [seek some law that would allow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound#Dependence_on_the_properties_of_the_medium) combinations of different gases for the speed of sound.

> Humidity has a small but measurable effect on sound speed (causing it to increase by about 0.1%-0.6%), because oxygen and nitrogen molecules of the air are replaced by lighter molecules of water. This is a simple mixing effect.

I would assume that you have a measure of the atmospheric pressure as well as the temperature.  [An approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water#Approximation_formula) of the maximum water vapor pressure would then be suitable.  I then put this in terms of pressure ratios, which is also the number ratio if I understand correctly.  If you have a better computer program to do the lookup, then might be necessary in practice.  This answer could only hope to establish viability in principle anyway.

$$ r = \frac{ P_{H_2O} }{ P} = \frac{ \exp\left(20.386-\frac{5132\,\mathrm{K}}{T}\right)\,\mathrm{mmHg} }{ P } $$

The best equation for the speed of sound in a gas is the following.

$$ c = \sqrt{ \frac{ \gamma k T }{ m } } $$

Some values for normal conditions:

- air: gamma = 1.4     m = 28.97 amu
- water:   gamma = 1.33        m = 18 amu

The adiabatic index does change with conditions, but it changes significantly less-so than other values, so it's the best one to take as constant (for each species) for the purposes of proof-of-principle.  Then as per the argument for the speed of sound in mixed gases, I would just presume that we algebraically combine the air and the water vapor for these values.

$$ \gamma' = x r \gamma_{H_20} + (1-x r) \gamma \\
m' = x r m_{H_20} + (1-x r) m $$

I wrote an extra $x$ variable, in order to indicate that the humidity is some fraction of the maximum possible humidity, which is the entire idea as I understand it.

So I think I've defined how to find everything.  The idea is that you measure $c$, so that's the equation that would be solved.  So it's just an iterative solve for $T$, if that's what you want.

Could there be problems?  Absolutely.  My calculation for speed of sound in pure steam is something like $491 m/s$, which is about 25% higher than for dry air.  But in normal conditions the maximum humidity is something like 2.3% partial pressure.  That means that the largest range we could imagine for the speed of sound is more like a 5% range with regard to humidity.

But I guess the biggest question is, if you have an accurate measure of $P$, why can you not get an accurate measure of $T$.  But maybe it would make sense, I don't know what you're doing.  Hope this helps.

Comment: For P I use 101.325 kpa as I read the effect of pressure is very small on speed of sound. I am trying to do a calibration process for motion tracking system using ultrasound sensors. I get some position errors so I am trying to check where the error is coming from. story short some routine require finding the temperature given the speed of sound and relative humidity. Physics is not my field as I work in Image processing so I find it some how hard to deal with it. I tried to use the equations in http://www.kyu.edu.tw/93/epaperv7/048.pdf but still it requires T to get T?!

Comment: @Salama Well that source has equations that are at least highly similar to mine.  I'm wondering if maybe your confusion is doing an implicit solve.  With the equations I wrote, you can get an equation with only T and all over values plugged in.  I stop there, because I assume you would use a computer to solve that numerically.  I mean, you'd use a root finding routine.  There's no simple way to accomplish your goal without that.  If you can do a root find "requiring T to get T" isn't necessarily a problem.  But I'm not totally sure if I've understood your problem.